# Getting error in persist Mock object

Tags: mocking, phpunit

I'm working on PHPUnit test case so need to create mock object but getting error

code:

UserControllerTest.php :

```
$user = $this->getMock('\User', array('Methods Name'));
$user->expects($this->once())
    ->method('Methods Name');
```

Pass this User Mock object from my controller :

```
userControllerService->userRequest($user);
```

My userRequest() in UserController:

```
$objUserRequest->setUser($user`);
```

I need to persist this user object in DB but throw "Argument 1 passed to must be an instance of MyBundle\Entity\MyEntity, instance of Mock_MyEntity_183626da given"

Answer (score 2):

The \User class must be fully qualified - either add in the full namespace (even if you are using `use` statements, you still need the fully qualified path) or use `User::class`

```
$this->getMock('\Full\Path\Required\User', ['Methods Name']);
$this->getMock(User::class); // if you have the namespace in the file with 'use'
```

Comment: hello @John i do this but this is not actual solution i have problem when persist User object in UserRequest Entity that time got the error.

Comment: Update your code with the namespace change. Where does the User class sit in your namespace?

Comment: My User entity located in : AppBundle\Entity\User

Comment: post your whole UserControllerTest.php file.